# How to update, insert and delete Redshift database using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am able to create table using psycopg2 library however I am unable to update and delete records in Redshift database. Please suggest some methods to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of good information in their documentation: [here](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html)

Here's a small snippet for your reference.

```py
with conn.cursor() as sql_cursor:
  sql_cursor.execute('delete from table_1 where col1=123')
```

Also, make sure the db user you are using to update or delete has permission to do so.